# Linking Boost - undefined reference to `boost::serialization::singleton_module::get_lock()'

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, compilation, dynamic-linking

I have my own library `mylib`, which uses Boost serialization library and links it dynamically. Now I want to link my library to another code - the command looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/g++-8   -Wall -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/net_test_ode_1.dir/net_test_ode_1.cpp.o  -o ../bin/examples/net_test_ode_1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/martin/MyLib/build/lib:/home/martin/MyLib/external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib ../lib/libmylib.so ../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_system.so ../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so ../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_random.so 
../lib/libmylib.so: undefined reference to `boost::serialization::singleton_module::get_lock()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see, I'm linking not only `libmylib.so`, but also `libboost_serialization.so`, so there shouldn't be any missing dependencies.

Still, I'm getting this undefined reference error. It's even more confusing, because I've already linked it to my library, so it shouldn't be needed here, if I understand it correctly.

Do you know, what am I doing wrong?

---

#### CMakeLists.txt - my library

```
if ("${BUILD_LIB}" STREQUAL "yes")
    add_library(mylib SHARED
        source codes...       
    )

    set_target_properties(
        mylib

        PROPERTIES
            INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${ROOT_DIR}/include;${SRC_DIR};${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
            LINK_LIBRARIES "${BOOST_LIBRARIES}"
            ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
            LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
    )
```

#### CMakeLists.txt - my executable

```
add_executable(net_test_1 net_test_1.cpp)

set_target_properties(
    net_test_1

    PROPERTIES
        INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${ROOT_DIR}/include"
        LINK_LIBRARIES "mylib;${BOOST_LIBRARIES}"
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/examples"
)
```

---

### EDIT:

According to compor's comment, I've added

```
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${BOOST_LIBRARIES})
```

to the CMakeLists with my library and

```
target_link_libraries(net_test_1 PUBLIC mylib)
```

to the CMakeLists with my executable.

I've also removed the line with `LINK_LIBRARIES` from `set_target_properties()`, but it doesn't change anything, unfortunately, and the problem still persists.

---

### EDIT 2:

I've tried to use `-rpath-link` according to ChrisD's comment, but the result is still the same

```
/usr/bin/g++   -Wall -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/net_test_ode_1.dir/net_test_ode_1.cpp.o  -o ../bin/examples/net_test_ode_1 -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/martin/MyLibRepo/external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib ../lib/libmylib.so ../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_system.so ../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so ../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_random.so
../lib/libmylib.so: undefined reference to `boost::serialization::singleton_module::get_lock()'
```

---

I've found out, that when I add `-lboost_serialization` to the compilation command, it works without the error. How is that possible? I thought, that adding `../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so` to the command is enough, as it points to the correct library.

Comment: You should use the variable `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`. In CMake variable names case matters.

Comment: @vre `BOOST_LIBRARIES` is my own variable and it is really written in capitals.

Comment: [This page](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/) may be useful, especially the sections about `-rpath-link`.

Comment: @Eenoku You should be using [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) instead of setting properties manually. The command, depending on the option of `PRIVATE|INTERFACE|PUBLIC` will take care of transitive dependencies for you. Currently, you're setting the Boost libraries to the equivalent of using `PRIVATE`, instead of `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` that would set the [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) property.

Comment: @compor Thank you for your advice! I've tried to use `target_link_libraries`, but it doesn't seem to be the problem in my case... Do you have any other idea? Or do you need more information?

Comment: @compor Also, as we can see, `libboost_serialization.so` already was being linked to my executable, so it could read from the it.

Comment: @Eenoku is your executable using boost? if not, then you need to consider the `-rpath-link` as @ChrisD suggested.

Comment: @compor I've tried it, but it gives me still the same error. Am I using it the right way?

Comment: @ChrisD Thank you for your suggestion! I've tried it, as can be seen in EDIT2, but it still is not working - am I using `-rpath-link` wrong?

Comment: @compor I've found out, that adding `-lboost_serialization` works - but I have no idea, why the library isn't linked properly, when I'm adding it by the relative path `../../external_dependencies/boost/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so`.

Comment: @Eenoku Ah, I saw this too late, while posting an attempt to an answer. Just throwing libraries at the linker does not work; the `-l` flag is used for just [that](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld). Objects are another matter.

Comment: What version of boost? We have this problem with boost-1.64 and not in boost-1.68. `get_lock()` definition was moved from `singleton.cpp` to `singleton.hpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I conjured a minimal Boost project that uses the serialization library.

Project structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── mylib
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── mylib.cpp
    └── mylib.hpp
```

app/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(app app.cpp)
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC mylib)
target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC mylib)
```

mylib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(mylib mylib.cpp)

target_include_directories(mylib PUBLIC 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

project(ser CXX)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS serialization REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(app)
add_subdirectory(mylib)
```

I believe you need to use the variables as set by the `find_package`, as those are procured in a way that matches your system installation. You can always go through the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) and influence whatever aspect you require.